# What does $\int dz \,d\bar z\,\partial_z \,f(z,\bar z)$ evaluate to?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Consider the following integral over the whole complex plane in $z,\bar z$
$$\int dz \,d\bar z\,\partial_z \,f(z,\bar z)$$
where $f(z,\bar z)$ is some well behaved function.

The two variables $z,\bar z$ are related by complex conjugation $\bar z=(z)^*$, so that we cannot simply 'cancel' the partial derivative and integration in $z$ up to some boundary terms. Still, does the presence of the holomorphic partial derivative $\partial_z$ in the integrand tell us something non-trivial about the integral? Does it simplify somehow?

Comment: Express anything in differential forms, you can convert the integral to boundary terms using Stoke's theorem.

$$\int_\Omega \partial_z f dz \wedge d\bar{z}
= \int_\Omega (\partial_z f dz + \partial_{\bar{z}} f d\bar{z}) \wedge d\bar{z}
= \int_\Omega df \wedge d\bar{z}
= \int_\Omega d( fd\bar{z})
= \int_{\partial\Omega} fd\bar{z}
$$
If you are concerned that $z$ and $\bar{z}$ are complex conjugates and whether above manipulation is valid, you can express intermediate steps in terms of $x, y$ and you will get same final answer.

Comment: @achillehui Awesome, this looks good, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My own attempt at making sense of this integral is as follows:

For instance, consider transforming the complex variables back to simple euclidean variables via

$$z=x+iy~~,~~\bar z=x-iy$$

Then the integration measure transforms as

$$dz d\bar z=-2idxdy$$

And the holomorphic derivative is

$$\partial_z=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_x-i\partial_y)$$

Plugging this into the integral gives

$$-i\int dx dy(\partial_x-i\partial_y)f(x,y)=-i\int dy[f(x,y)]_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty}-\int dx[f(x,y)]_{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty}$$

So that indeed the integral kind of simplifies to some boundary terms in some of the components...